# AJAX request returns missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, select

I am struggling with my 1st AJAX based application and need help. I keep getting this error message

```
Template is missing

Missing template my_apps/refresh, application/refresh with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/csco/MyApps/app/views"
```

I have a Ruby on Rails form that has multiple scroll down menus. I want to trigger an AJAX request each time the user changes his selections so that some text fields of the form are updated in real time without need to press a button or reloading the whole page.

These are the relevant pieces of my code:

Excerpt of partial form app/views/my_apps/_form.html.erb used by new and edit methods

```
<%= form_for(@my_app, :html => {:name => "MyAppInfo"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :"Program Administrator" %>
  <select class="prog_man_class" id=Program_Manager onChange="this.form.get_results_button_name.click()">
    <option value="1">Admin1</option>
    <option value="2">Admin2</option>
    <option value="3">Admin3</option>
  </select>

// more select menus here

// some Ruby code here that ends by assigning a value to the field I want to be
// updated in real time, I called it Total Power ; Total Power value depends on
// the user's selection of Admin1, Admin2, or Admin3, as well as other selected options

  <% @my_app.TotalPower=total_power %>

  <%= f.label :"Total Power" %>
  <%= f.text_field :TotalPower, :size => 6, :style => "text-align:right" %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Get Results", :name => "get_results_button_name", :remote => "true" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Excerpt of app/controllers/my_app.rb

```
class MyAppController < ApplicationController

// other methods like index, show, new, edit, create, and destroy are here -->

  # PUT /my_apps/1
  # PUT /my_apps/1.json
  def update
    @my_app = MyApp.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_app.update_attributes(params[:my_app])
        format.html { render :action => "refresh", :notice => 'Update SUCCESSFUL!' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @my_app.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/my_apps/refresh.js.erb (I also tried renaming it refresh.js.rjs with no luck either)

```
page.replace_html('TotalPower', render(@TotalPower))
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a `app/views/my_apps/refresh.html.erb` file for the html format? This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Finbarr for your answer. I added a refresh.html.erb file there, but then it simply loads that file whatever it contains, so there is no AJAX based refresh taking place

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem simply by reverting the order of format.html and format.js like below. I don't know if it's the proper way but it worked for me and I don't see the missing template error anymore.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @my_app.update_attributes(params[:my_app])
    format.js
    format.html { render :action => "refresh", :notice => 'Update SUCCESSFUL!' }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.json { render :json => @my_app.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your form is making a normal request and not an ajax request that's why it was trying to load `refresh.html` insted of your `refresh.js`. To solve that you need to include the remote option in your form like this i think:

```
<%= form_for(@my_app, :remote => true, :html => {:name => "MyAppInfo"}) do |f| %>
```

Don't exactly know where it goes, there or inside de html options hash try it until you see in your page's source coda that the form has de option `data-remote="true"`.

Comment: Think this is the correct answer, he adds the remote atribute to he submit button but he needs to add it to the whole form